# Polygon getting clipped in export to PDF at one scale but not another using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: polygon, display

[image: Screen-view at 1"=10']
This is what the screen view looks like when scale is set to 120 (1"=10')

---

[image: PDF Export at 1"=10']
This is what comes out in the PDF. Note the clipping in the upper left portion of the curved "path" at the 1:120 scale.

---

[image: PDF Export at 1" =15']
This is what comes out in the PDF when the scale is adjusted to 1:180 (1"=15')

---

The sheet is 11x17". All data are in a file geodatabase. The data is rotated 90 degrees. I have exported that single polygon to a different feature class with the same results. The results are also the same if I import that single polygon feature class into a fresh map document.

I'm completely befuddled. I plan to try a shapefile, but in the meantime I wonder if anyone else has any ideas as to why this is happening and what can be done.

Converting the shape to a shapefile fixed the situation, but doesn't satisfy my need to know what happened and why.

Comment: This may originate in your data, e.g. if you incoorporate data from AutoCAD containing specific features like curves, which are displayed faulty in GIS.

Comment: These shapes were drawn in ArcView using the standard editing tools.